# Swap JComboBox Selections

Tags: java

I have 2 JComboBoxes populated with the same entries (from an ENUM list)
I have action events for when the selected items change, but we have requirement I can't quite figure out.

The code is converting currencies... If Box1 = USD and Box2 = EURO, and I then change Box1 to = ERUO, I need Box2 to = USD. Below are my actionListeners

```
        fromCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String finalAmt = convertCurr(fromField.getText(),
                fromCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                toCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

            //Check for Errors
            try {
                Double.parseDouble(finalAmt);

                //CHANGE LABELS
                toLabel.setText(finalAmt + " " +
                    toCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

                toField.setText(String.valueOf(finalAmt));
            } catch (NumberFormatException  nfe) {
                fromLabel.setText(finalAmt);

                toLabel.setText(finalAmt);

                toField.setText(finalAmt);
            } finally {
                fromLabel.setText(fromField.getText() + " " +
                    fromCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() + " equals");
            }

        }
    });

    toCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String finalAmt = convertCurr(fromField.getText(),
                fromCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                toCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

            //Check for Errors
            try {
                Double.parseDouble(finalAmt);

                //CHANGE LABELS
                toLabel.setText(finalAmt + " " +
                    toCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

                toField.setText(String.valueOf(finalAmt));
            } catch (NumberFormatException  nfe) {
                fromLabel.setText(finalAmt);

                toLabel.setText(finalAmt);

                toField.setText(finalAmt);
            } finally {
                fromLabel.setText(fromField.getText() + " " +
                    fromCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() + " equals");
            }
        }
    });
    fromField.postActionEvent();
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Is more information needed?

edit: here is a sample, slimmed down, code base.

```
public class tDropDowns extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private final JComboBox<CurrencyConstant> fromCombo;
private final JComboBox<CurrencyConstant> toCombo;

public tDropDowns() {
    fromCombo = new JComboBox<>(CurrencyConstant.values());
    fromCombo.setName("fromCombo");

    toCombo = new JComboBox<>(CurrencyConstant.values());
    toCombo.setName("toCombo");

    // TODO: Layout code goes here...
    JPanel entryFields = new JPanel();
    entryFields.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //entryFields.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    entryFields.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    entryFields.add(fromCombo, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    entryFields.add(toCombo, gbc);

    this.add(entryFields);

    // Set initial values:
    fromCombo.setSelectedItem(CurrencyConstant.USD);
    toCombo.setSelectedItem(CurrencyConstant.EUR);

    fromCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    toCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{

}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Currency Converter Dropdowns");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    JComponent newContentPane = new tDropDowns();
    newContentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(newContentPane,
        BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(tDropDowns::createAndShowGUI);
}
```

}

Comment: If it's possible, please post your entire class so that it's easier to test the behaviour without having to build an entire JFrame myself.

Comment: I went ahead and stripped out the JFrame info to just be for the two drop downs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the detailed post. Here is the solution to your problem. I put a comment on each applied ternary operator in order to make it clear what the code does here.

What you have to do is to find out, what the currency is you currently set in the clicked ComboBox. And then set the opposite currency in the other box. I solved this with the ternary operator.

```
    // Set initial values:
    fromCombo.setSelectedItem(CurrencyConstant.USD);
    toCombo.setSelectedItem(CurrencyConstant.EUR);

    fromCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            toCombo.setSelectedItem(
                // Is EUR in fromCombo selected? Then set USD in toCombo. Else set EUR in toCombo.
                (fromCombo.getSelectedItem() == CurrencyConstant.EUR) ? CurrencyConstant.USD : CurrencyConstant.EUR

            );
        }
    });

    toCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fromCombo.setSelectedItem(
                // Is EUR in toCombo selected? Then set USD in fromCombo. Else set EUR in fromCombo.
                (toCombo.getSelectedItem() == CurrencyConstant.EUR) ? CurrencyConstant.USD : CurrencyConstant.EUR

            );
        }
    });
```

You can now add the rest of your code which triggers the currency computation and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. this did it.

Comment: My pleasure. :)